# Regarding reading data from a port

Tags: c#, sockets, communication, port

I have an application that sends data over a port. I need to accept the data (on the same system ) and then write it in a text file. Now the problem is that I don't know how to go about doing it.

I am working on Windows XP. And any platform that enables me to accept the data and write it into a text file would do.But preferably C#.net platform.

Please help.

Data is sent over a network port. also is there any generic way to accept data because the application that is sending data has not been developed by me so am not really sure in what form it would be sending the data. Or is there any way to check the same?

Comment: http://socketprogramming.blogspot.com/

Comment: @olive: So if you think an answer helped you, you should upvote it and if it solved your problem you should mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you didn't say what kind of port you like to use. But the .Net framework has for the most of dataflows some kind of [`Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) implementation.

- So if you have a serial port you could take the [`SerialPort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx).
- If you have a network connection you could take the [`Socket` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx).
- If you have a file you could take the [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx).

All of these classes have some open, close, read and write functions. And you could simple open two streams, read the first one and put the output as input into the second one. That's it.

If you have any further questions about something more concrete doesn't work, feel free to update your question or ask a new one.

Comment: @olive: as already stated in the comment to your question, you should at least upvote this answer and/or mark it as accepted if it answered your question.